# Crystal Reports Date Parameter format

Tags: date, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a date parameter in my report, which pulls data based on a date in the report which is formatted mm/dd/yyyy. However when the parameter prompts for an input, the parameter requests the date in yyyy-mm-dd.

When entered, data is still correctly shown, however for the user I'd prefer the parameter to be shown mm/dd/yyyy.

How do I change how the parameter date formatting?

Comment: Is your parameter showing data from some database field or custom data?

Comment: It's showing a formula field where I'm converting a Date and Time to Date. Formula: Date({my.field}). The result is date formatted MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

All date `Parameter` from your Crystal Report must set as string format.

Do not rely on date itself

for example you have a date in your query something like:

`20190322` your parameter must looks like this so that it will match when passing it.